# Fetching data on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to fetch some data on rails database. The problem is, the ActiveRecord tutorials around doesn't help very much on my problem.

I need to get a Name(foreign key), email and amount of sold credits from a DB, and make a HTML Table with that. The table is a html partial render inside a Admin Area HTML. Where did a write the code to get the data and pass to view? On controller, model, i get lost on that, i tried the '@var = User.all' on controller but didn't get any result on view, something is missing and i clearly don't get the rails logic hehe

On 'home_controller', which is inside a 'admin_area' folder, i got

```
def top_coaches
 @var = Coach.all
end
```

Then, my view follows a path, where the 'routes' had home/index as root

```
root to: "home#index"
```

On index i render '_top-coaches.html.haml' as partial

```
  %h1 Top Coaches
  = render partial: 'admin_area/home/partials/top-coaches'
```

which has this on it

```
%ul
  - @var.each do |coach|
    %li= coach.name
```

This doesn't do nothing, it renders the partial if a put some *h1* or *p*, but i cant get the data i need to make a table

Comment: The controller generally queries models `User.all` and then controller passes instance variables like `@var` (perferably `@users` for reability) to the view. The view should use these instance variables to display data. So in your view you would need to have a looping mechanism of some kind that uses `@var` to display the user data. e.g. `<ul><% @var.each do |user| %> <li><%= user.name %=></li><%end%></ul>` will display an unordered list of user names. All of this assumes that you actually have users in the database

Comment: Can you show your code? it's hard to guide without knowing what you have tried

Comment: Updated with the code, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Are you calling the top_coaches method in your HomeController index method at all? Can you verify your admin_area/home/index view is rendering.

Comment: is Coach.all empty?

Comment: Coach.all in rails console returns the database results, it had 2 entries.

Comment: The admin_area/home/index renders, _top-coaches partials too

Comment: Ok, are you calling the top_coaches method in your HomeController index method?

Comment: I believe so, but now i not sure exactly what are you refering on calling the method. Inside my 'home_controller.rb' i get the 'def top_coaches' that defines the @var = Coach.all

Comment: on "home_controller.rb" i dont get a "def index" method. maybe what are you refering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this in your HomeController:

```
def index
  top_coaches
end
```

In your routes file, root to: 'home#index' tells rails to look for the HomeController and invoke the index method.

Since you said in the comments that you do not have that defined. It's inherited from ApplicationController, so in the code above your overriding it (at least i'm pretty sure that's what's going on, someone correct me if I'm wrong), so now your top_coaches method will be called and your @var instance variable will be set.

Comment: Thats it, now it renders the results from the DB. First i changed the name from top_coaches to index itselft, but index with top_coaches inside works as well. Thanks

Comment: Ah good call on the name change, glad it worked. Also, I recommend at least skimming through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. 

I really love how easy it is to get things done in Rails because of how much it does for you behind the scenes, but if your'e not familiar with how or why things work the way they do you can find yourself scratching your head for _hours_.